# Hiding navigation bar outside full-screen mode

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, fullscreen

I would like to have a non-fullscreen window of Mozilla Firefolx with a hidden navigation- and tool-bar. Is there a way to do this? Or alternatively, are there browsers that can do this?

Comment: I found a solution for Google Chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124877/how-do-you-hide-the-address-bar-in-google-chrome-for-chrome-apps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Chrome, by amending the shortcut to have the following flags

`--chrome-frame  --kiosk "http://www.google.com"`

Comment: For me this makes it full-screen.